# JavaScript not running in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I made header.jsp and footer.jsp to make dynamic pages. In the accumulated code JavaScript is not running.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CAN Invoicing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="top:10;height:200px;">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <a href="/"><img src="/images/Amazon-CAN-Logo.png" alt="CAN INVOICING"></img></a>
      </div>
      <div style="float:right;top:200px;">
        <img src="/images/logo_csmetrics.gif" alt="Powered By CSBI"><img>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="top:200px;">
      <h1>you are authorized login User ::null</h1>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function doTest()
        {
          alert("hello");
        }
      </script>
      <h2>Session username swasri</h2>
      <a href="/test/"target="_blank">test</a>
      <a href="/upload/" target="_blank">uplaod</a>
      <a href="/uploadS3/" target="_blank">s3</a>
      <a href="/readS3/" target="_blank">downloadS3</a>
    </div>
    <div><p>footer</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The dynamic part starts from `<h2>` till footer div. I am using tomcat apache server to run above code. All the jsps are kept inside webapp folder.

I am running above code in tomcat apache webserver.

Comment: If you mean *not working* by the `alert` not appearing, you might consider calling `doTest()` in order to run the function.

Comment: Where do you call that script?

Comment: What's with the `</img>` end tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the doTest() function.

```
 <html>
 <title>CAN Invoicing</title>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function doTest()
        {
            alert("hello");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:doTest();">
<div style="top:10;height:200px;">
<div style="float:left;"><a href="/"><img src="/images/Amazon-CAN-Logo.png" alt="CAN INVOICING"></img></a></div>
<div style="float:right;top:200px;"><img src="/images/logo_csmetrics.gif" alt="Powered By CSBI"><img></div>
</div>          
<div style="top:200px;">
<h1>you are authorized login User ::null</h1>   
<h2>Session username swasri</h2>
<a href="/test/"target="_blank">test</a>
<a href="/upload/" target="_blank">uplaod</a>
<a href="/uploadS3/" target="_blank">s3</a>
<a href="/readS3/" target="_blank">downloadS3</a>
</div>
<div><p>footer</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the `doTest()` function, right now it isn't being called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doTest() {
     alert("hello");
  }

  doTest();
</script>
```